# DbGeography search query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, time-limit-exceeded, geospatial

I have a situation in which I need to get the closest road to a `DbGeography` point.

This takes 5 - 8 seconds to run in some cases.

I have a `Spatial_Index` on the column and I re-organised it, so it is not fragmented.

This query is quite heavy, sometimes the CPU usage raises to 100% because of this.

This is what the table looks like:

[image]

Here is the spatial result (in case it helps):

[image]

```
    public string GetRoad(DbGeography point)
    {
        var name = "";
        try
        {
            using (var gisEntities = new GISSpatialEntities())
            {
                var query = String.Format(@"
                            DECLARE @point geography;
                            SET @point = geography::STPointFromText('POINT({0} {1})', 4326);                              

                            SELECT TOP 10 * FROM GeographyLine
                            WHERE GeoLine.STIsValid() =1 AND  @point.STBuffer(200).STIntersects(GeoLine) = 1
                            ORDER BY GeoLine.STDistance(@point)", point.Longitude, point.Latitude);
                var firstOrDefault = gisEntities.GeographyLines.SqlQuery(query).FirstOrDefault();
                if (firstOrDefault != null)
                {
                    name = firstOrDefault.LineName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = string.Format("Exception in GetRoad() - {0} - Inner [{1}] \r\n", ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
            _logger.LogMessage(MessageType.Error, msg);
        }
        return name;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Instead of doing `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ...` you should only retrieve the columns needed which in your case is `LineName`.
- `var name = ""` doesn't need to be there, if you just `return firstOrDefault.LineName` and for no result/exception return `string.Empty`.
- While we are at `var firstOrDefault` I would like to say that using `var` here is just wrong because it isn't clear from the right side of the assignment what the type is. The variable name `firstOrDefault` isn't descriptive enough so you should consider using maybe `geographyLine` or `foundGeographyLine`.
- You are selecting the `TOP 10` but using `FirstOrDefault`. This just doesn't seem right. Using `SELECT TOP 1` would be much better and faster.

Comment: Do you think it will better to write this Query in LINQ and Entity Framework instead of getting EF to execute this Query.

Comment: I don't see any advantage of using Linq here. You already have (after you change the SELECT) a easy to read (and hopefully performant) query.

Comment: I checked the Database, and found that the condition GeoLine.STIsValid() =1 was not required. And I also changed Top 10 to Top 1. And Performance increased. Now it takes miliseconds to perform same query